# Delete draft sms in ICS

Tags: sms, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I see there are some other threads here about the same thing but they are not for ICS.

If I start to write a sms to someone and not send it the text will be stored as a draft. 
How can I delete this?

The only options I can see is to delete the entire thread witch is not really an option.

Has anyone found the trix?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know if there's an easier way to do this but I just long-press the previously entered text, select all of the text (the weird grid icon in the top right in text selection mode) and hit backspace on the keyboard to delete it all. When the text area is blank it will no longer put the "Draft" notification on the thread.

Comment: On my phone this just solves the problem a small time. After some time the draft text will come back.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time trying to figure out how to delete drafts in outlook on my Samsung A tablet and discovered by accident, all I had to do was swipe the draft left and it deleted.  So simple, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.